# MyAutoScaleFactor may cause a runtime exception because it is a field of a marshal-by-reference class

Tags: c#

```
return new Size(bounds.Right - bounds.Left + (int)(form.MyAutoScaleFactor.Width * 4), bounds.Bottom - bounds.Top);
```

but i get warning of

```
Warning 2   Accessing a member on 'NonFullscreen.MessageBoxForm.MyAutoScaleFactor' may cause a runtime exception because it is a field of a marshal-by-reference class  C:\Projekti\Skladiscenje\Skladiscenje\NonFullscreen\MessageBoxForm.cs   244 60  NonFullscreen
```

how can i prevent runtime exception?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to [the docs for that warning](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x524dkh4.aspx), something like this may help (by extracting to a local variable first):

```
var scaleFactor = form.MyAutoScaleFactor;

return new Size(bounds.Right - bounds.Left + (int)(scaleFactor.Width * 4),
                bounds.Bottom - bounds.Top);
```